# How do I best solve multiple component modifications via a single event?

Tags: entity-system, events, messaging

I'm trying to solve multiple component modifications via a single event. Is there a better way of handling this?

I have an a label entity that cares about when a shield entity's hitpoints component is modified (damage, regeneration, etc).

The label will need to change

- its text to display the current % of shield remaining.
- its text color to display the severity of shield remaining.

When my `ShieldSystem` resolves the `hitPoints` component, the below code runs. For eah type of modification I plan to listen for, I need to add a new `if`-statement to the `for`-loop. This means I have a bunch of duplicated code between systems if more than one wants to modify any listening text component, sprite component, etc.

```
for(int i =0; i < listeners.size(); i++)
{
    if(listeners.count(MessageType::CHANGE_TEXT) == 1)
    {
        std::vector<Entity*> entities =  listeners[MessageType::CHANGE_TEXT];
        for(int j; j < entities.size(); j++)
        {
            Entity* e = entities[j];
            MessageInfo* messageInfo = new MessageInfo(MessageType::CHANGE_TEXT, e, "Some Text");
            MessageCenter::Dispatch(messageInfo);
        }
    }

    // Add an If(listeners.count(MessageType::CHANGE_TEXT_COLOR)...

    // Add an If(listeners.count(MessageType::CHANGE_SPRITE_RECT)...

    // etc

}
```

Comment: I can answer this question if you state your question better. What exactly is your question? Please make sure this is clear.

Comment: Hopefully I've clarified my question!

Comment: This seems to be more about code review than game development. Did you know we have a [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), currently in beta? (We could ask a moderator to migrate this over there.)

Comment: Oh cool, that's probably exactly the place I'm looking for. I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make this easier to use is to let a user emit message types.

Check out some [example implementation](https://bitbucket.org/rgaul/sel/src/59c72bbe6c7dc4a23f40fdd5054cf52d12a7fabf/src/SEL/Core/?at=default) (see Messenger.h and .cpp).

The idea is to let a user do something like this:

```
// Subscribe to a particular message type as a user
messenger.Subscribe( MSG_type, CallThisFunction );

// Notify the client
messenger.Emit( MSG_type ) // calls CallThisFunction
```

A good way to pass along parameters with a message is to have some generic way to send data. Then you can let the user (in this case inside of `CallThisFunction` deal with retrieving the data appropriately (typecasting, or some other more intelligent means). This lets the notifier use an alternate Emit version:

```
// Notify the client with 4 params, pass each
// param to the CallThisFunction
messenger.Emit( MSG_type, somePtr, 5, 1.0f, "a string" );
```

All in all this mostly looks like an API issue.

Comment: Wow I was so close! I have all those pieces you mentioned but wasn't using them properly. It never occurred to me to subscribe a particular function to a message type, and then having the dispatcher field in passed params from a calling method. Thank you Randy, made my day!

Comment: Just one more thing, there's no way of getting around having those multiple if-chains for each system?

Comment: Never mind my above comment. I moved all that code into the BaseSystem super class as a protected method. Now all systems will just need to call that message and pass a message type and params, the super class method will do the message dispatching appropriately.

Comment: @StephenPanagiotis Hey I'm glad you figured it out :)